# How do I catch the null value from my JtextField?

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextfield

I have a JTExfield and if the user leaves the textfield empty I wanna catch it up and set the string to "NULL" 
It works if I write blablabla or whatever into the string and it should do but I also wanna catch if they leave it empty and put the text "NULL" into my file.

I have tried two solutions no one is working :

When user click ok button it performs this:

```
setPicture(pictureTextField.getText());
```

which is calling this method :

```
public void setPicture(String picture) {

            if (picture == null) {

                picture = "NULL";

            }

            this.picture = picture;
        }
```

and :

```
public void setPicture(String picture) {

        if (picture == "") {

            picture = "NULL";

        }

        this.picture = picture;
    }
```

So to repeat what I want to do is to set my picture String to "NULL" is the user leaves the textField empty.

Comment: `JTextField.getText()` does not return `null` but an empty string when the text is empty. Try `if (picture.isEmpty())`.

Comment: .equals("") !!! I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the null and empty checks together:

```
public void setPicture(String picture) {

  if (picture == null || picture.isEmpty()) {

    picture = "NULL";

  }

  this.picture = picture;
}
```

Comment: @Sembrano : Please accept the answer if it has helped. Refer this link to check how accepting answer helps. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You can check this in two ways...

1] checks if `String` is empty...

```
if ( "".equals(picture.trim()) ) {

    picture = "NULL";

}
```

2] checks if `String` length is 0...

```
if ( picture.trim().length() == 0 ) {

    picture = "NULL";

}
```

Comment: @Sembrano isEmpty() internally checks the length of string and return true if it is 0, check it here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty(), another thing you should worry about is isEmpty() was introduced in java 1.6, so it will not work in 1.5 or before..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(pictureTextField.getText().length()>1){
    //nothing in text field. Here you can set null
}else {
     // text field contains something
}
```

or try

```
pictureTextField.getText().equals("")
```